# In which situation does the electric field vary sinusoidally with position?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

If I have a point charge *q* at the origin then the electric field will be
$$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q}{r^2} \hat r $$ that is to say that electric field will diminish by the square of distance as increase the distance from our point charge.
If we have a continuous surface charge in rectangular form with size very large then the electric field will be $$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} \hat r $$ that is to say that electric field will be same everywhere.
But the problem comes when we go to **Electromagnetic Waves**, you see an **EM** wave is generally pictured as  [image] 
which I think is a snapshot of the wave at some time t.

Now, my problem is: if we assume that red axis is our $x-$axis then you see our electric field is varying sinusoidally with this position $x$ at a particular time and I can't imagine how is it possible for an electric field to have a maximum value at some point and then have the same maximum value at some other point which is farther from the previous point? Actually I'm so used to the inverse square law that I'm not able to imagine the contradiction that how can field every increase with distance? It should diminish with as $\frac{1}{r^2}$ or as $\frac{1}{r}$ (in case of infinite line charge) or should not diminish at all (infinite surface charge). But I find this sinusoidal variation quite hard to imagine. I mean how can electric field ever increase with increase in distance (you see when those red arrows become sufficiently small they start rising up again).
Please provide me some illustration as in which condition electric field gonna vary sinusoidally?
Thank you, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is that you are thinking about electrostatics, where the only relevant quantity is the electric field. EM waves don't exist in electrostatics, but electrodynamics (as in Maxwell's equations).

Comment: The figure included here is making the rounds ... and it is incorrect if the arrow labeled "C" is the direction of propagation.  With the E and B fields shown, the propagation would be in the opposite direction.

Comment: @garyp You're right, but what's a negative sign but a cultural construct ... :P

Answer (score 1):

The graph depicts the field of a *plane wave*, for which the amplitude does not vary with distance.

Plane waves are infinite in transverse extent (and longitudinal extent, for that matter), so they are unphysical, but they do describe the behavior of waves in volumes that are small enough that spatial variations can be ignored.  Waves whose origin is a point source (or view the field very far from a compact source) obey the inverse square law.  But if you take a small enough volume of the field of a point source, the field won't vary much with distance.  It resembles a plane wave.   The ideal plane wave is a *model* of such a situation.

Comment: Your second paragraph is clear to me but your first paragraph, when you said *for which the amplitude doesn’t vary with time* is not understandable by me @AaronStevens  is trying to explain me that *amplitude* thing but I’m not able to understand it. I’m viewing that diagram as if the source charge is at the intersection of those red, blue and c axes and as I move along c-axis I’m moving farther and hence field should diminish even if the charge is vibrating sinusoidally.

Comment: Your interpretation is not correct.  The source *cannot be* at that intersection.   The source must be a compact source very far away.  A star would be a very good example.   The amplitude here on earth does not change with distance very much at a distance of one million light years from the source.

Comment: Yes. But why then there is wavy electric field shown in the picture of EM wave? What does that really convey? By the way thank you for your very clear explanations.

Comment: The EM wave, like any other wave, has a wavelength.  That's what's being displayed.

Comment: Wavelength means distance between two crests, so what is the crest here? According to me the crest is the max amplitude of $E$ and that’s my problem why $E$ is fluctuating at all when you have said that $E$ wouldn’t change in small volume?

Comment: The word "amplitude" can mean *maximum field strength in a cycle* or *instantaneous field strength*.   Let the maximum field strength in a cycle be $A$.  Then the instantaneous amplitude varies between $-A$ and $A$ in the course of one cycle.  My small volume is large enough to contain many wavelengths, but small enough that the maximum field strength in a cycle does not change appreciably.

Comment: Sir, my question is why the electric field is going in a wavy manner? As far as my knowledge every electric field should be inversely squared to distance and as I say that my image is a snapshot at a time t, therefore we can assume that my charge is static and hence field should vary as inverse square of distance. What's causing the field to *increase and then decrease and then increase again and so on....* ?

Comment: You are making *many* unfounded assumptions, and drawing conclusions from them.  #1:  " every electric field should be inversely squared to distance"  *Not true!* #2 "we can assume that my charge is static"  *Not true!*  #3 " the source charge is at the intersection of those red, blue and c axes"  *Not true!*  Sit back.  Reread comments.  Think.  Don't add your own spin on what you see, and what people are trying to tell you.

Comment: Okay sir I will try to forget everything and then read your answer and comments. I will let you know if even after that I get some problem, am I allowed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100050/discussion-between-knight-and-garyp).

Answer (score 0):

The inverse-square law has very little to do with your graph. Like you said, it is a time snapshot of the EM wave showing the field strength and direction of a polarized wave at several points **along the C axis**.  There is no depiction of what the E-field is along the red axis, i.e., the red axis is not a spatial dimension. Your graph is depicting only one spatial dimension. That's the source of your confusion, plus it's not static field from a point source.

Comment: *Your graph is depicting only one spatial dimension* .  Will not electric field change as it is shown? Kindly explain me, I need it.

Comment: @Knight Your picture shows vectors at points along the c-axis. Just because the arrows extend to above this axis does not mean the picture is showing the field at those points. Remember for a vector field a vector quantity is assigned to each point in space. In this diagram they have only shown the vectors at the points in space along the c-axis.

Comment: @Knight The lengths of the red arrows do not indicate position. They indicate the strength of the E-field at the C-axis location. Move to a different C-location and the E-field is different.

Comment: @BillN yes that’s only I’m saying. As we move along the c-axis the magnitude of electric field is increasing  which is against the inverse square Law.

Comment: @BillN I apologise for asking an off-topic question but can you please explain the thing in your **about** section. I mean *I like to know how things $\int\vec{F}\cdot\vec{dr}$*

Comment: @Knight $\int \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$ is work. The graph is of an EM wave, not the field from a static point charge, as I say in my answer. You are only going to get an inverse square curve for E vs x with a static point charge. If you have a distribution of charges or moving charges, you won't get an inverse square relation for the total field.

Comment: @BillN But as I say that picture is  a snapshot and hence the charge is static and inverse square should be followed, isn't it?

Comment: @Knight No, a snapshot does not mean that the charge distribution which created the wave is static. Static means that the distribution is at rest at ALL times. The snapshot is a picture of the current values of the E-field at various locations due to all the previous motions of charges.